# How can I remove a line that contains a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I know some people may say the solution is with `sed` but it didn't work for me
so, the thing is that I read a var with `read var` then I want to know how to control if that var exists in a column specified by me of my archive, and if it doesnt just keep asking Please enter a valid code, and if its correct just delete that line. thanks

CODE

```
read var
sed -i '/$var/d' file.txt
```

And i want to put some short of tester that confirm if u put a valid code or not.

The structure of the file is

```
code;Name;Surname
```

Comment: Can you share your `sed` command and string/file you ran it on?

Comment: `read code``sed -i '/$code/d' file.txt` and i want to put some confirmation that the code is in the file

Comment: Yeah sure sorry, I was in a rush

Comment: you need double quotes in order to let shell var (`$code`) get expanded.

Comment: @cricket_007 Edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following used awk to search and remove lines which first column is `$code`. If a line is removed then awk will exit successfully and `break` will be called.

```
file="input_file"
while :; do
  echo "Enter valid code:"
  read -r code
  [ -n "$code" ] || continue
  awk -F';' -v c="$code" '$1 == c {f=1;next}1;END{exit(f?0:1)}' \
  "$file" > "$file.out" && break
done
mv "$file.out" "$file"
```

This will continue to ask for a code in `$file` until the user enters a valid code at which point `$file.out` is created and the iteration broken.

Then `file.out` is renamed to `file`. Technically `$file.out` is created each time.

Comment: It doesn't work well my file.txt dissapears and appears under the name of file.out

Comment: @nabmaster The `mv` command at the end should take care of that. Also change `file="..."` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no spaces or odd bits to parse, so **sed** needs no single quotes here:

```
read var
sed -i /"$var"/d file.txt
```

And a demo -- make a list from 1 to 3, remove 2:

```
seq 3 > three.txt; var=2; sed -i /"$var"/d three.txt ; cat three.txt
```

Outputs:

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `$var` or `${var}`expanded with

```
read var
sed -i '/'${var}'/d' file.txt
```

But what will happen when `$var` has a space? Nothing good, so use double quotes as well:

```
read var
sed -i '/'"${var}"'/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with awk in below file :

```
$cat test.txt
code;Name;Surname
xyz;n1;s1
abc;dd;ff
xyz;w;t
abc;ft;op
```

It will print the lines that is going to delete .But I am not able to figure out how to delete the line from awk after printing the info .

```
$var=xyz | awk -v var="$var" -F ";" '{ if ($1 == var ) print "FOUND " var " And Going to delete the line" NR " " $0  ; }' test.txt 
FOUND xyz And Going to delete the line2 xyz;n1;s1
FOUND xyz And Going to delete the line4 xyz;w;t
```

Below command will display the info and will delete the date . But it will take 2 parsing of the input file .

```
$var=xyz | awk -v var="$var" -F ";" '{ if ($1 == var ) print "FOUND " var " And Going to delete the line" NR " " $0  ; }' test.txt && awk -v var="$var" -F ";" '($1 != var)' test.txt > _tmp_  && mv _tmp_ test.txt
FOUND xyz And Going to delete the line2 xyz;n1;s1
FOUND xyz And Going to delete the line4 xyz;w;t
```

New File after deletion :

```
$cat test.txt
code;Name;Surname
abc;dd;ff
abc;ft;op
```